# Nested for loops-how many?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

How many nested for loops are possible in Java?
Can we keep on adding nested for loops till infinite?
How many for loops can Java compiler supports?

Comment: The compiler supports much more than any sane code reviewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limited stack size in the compiler; if you have too many nested loops, you will get a `StackOverflowError`.

I get a `StackOverflowError` if I run the following bash script (generating `N` nested for loops):

```
#!/bin/bash

N=800

(echo "class Test { void test() {"
yes "for (;;) {" | head -n "${N}"
yes "}" | head -n "${N}"
echo "} }") > Test.java

javac Test.java
```

(800 is not a tight bound; 700 compiles, 800 doesn't)

You can increase the size of the `javac` stack using the `-J-Xss` flag.

There is also a 64kB limit on a single method's bytecode size; if you are writing for loops which "do something", you might hit this limit before you blow the compiler's stack; the trivial for loops generated by the script above are optimized away to just one infinite loop by the compiler.